# Odoo With Nginx: a way to catch killed worker?

Tags: python, nginx, odoo, python-multiprocessing, worker

I'm running Odoo using `workers` parameter with non zero value and also use Nginx for reverse proxy. Setting workers to non zero value, enables multiprocessing. Then in Odoo configuration there is a paremeter called `limit_time_cpu`, which defaults to `60` (seconds). I increased that value, but during synchronization with another system it is still not enough and workers are killed, though synchronization is not complete.

So I need a way to know that the reason synchronization was not complete, is because worker was killed. Is there a way in python code to get such information at all?

For example if doing synchronization, worker runs out of time, it will log an event about that (but it should only log when running specific piece of code).

Like:

```
def sync(some_obj):
    # Start of synchronizaton
    # Now if worker was killed raise/log error?
    try:
        some_obj.do_synchro()
    except WorkerError:  # just as an example
        print "worker ran out of time"
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just increase the limit again or split the sync in more than one job? But i would like such a feature, too, because as of now the worker killing process lacks transparency.

Comment: Yes of course it is easier, but still it can happen even if you would increase the limit. I mean process might take so long that given increase would not be enough. And usually it is OK to kill it, because it might use resources unwisely. Anyway it would be good to know at some cases if worker was killed.